# How to store 24 Hour format in list in Android Kotlin

Tags: java, android, date, kotlin, calendar

Hey I want to return a list of time object of 24 hours of time frame. It means i need a logic to get hours in a list starting from 00.00 to 23.00. Inside the list [**00.00**,**01.00**,**02.00**,.....**23.00**]
. If i search a particular index like

```
println(timeList[3])
```

it will return

```
03.00.
```

How to i achieve this logic throught **Calendar** object or any other class. Does any one have idea about this how to get this type of list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use can create a `List` of `java.time.LocalTime`.

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<LocalTime> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
            list.add(LocalTime.of(i, 0));
        }

        System.out.println(list.get(3));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
03:00
```

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Using legacy API:**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, i);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            list.add(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
        }

        System.out.println(list.get(3));

    }
}
```

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: Looks like exactly what you need, @vivekmodi

Comment: Hi @Arvind sir thanks for your reply. **list.add(LocalTime.of(i, 0));** **LocalTime.of** is giving error **Call requires API level 26 (current min is 16): java.time.LocalTime#of**

Comment: @vivekmodi - I've posted a solution using the legacy API as well.

Comment: Before resorting to `Calendar`, a poorly designed and long outdated class, please do yourself the favour of following the links to *Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring* and to *ThreeTen-Backport*.

Answer (score 3):

The kotlin version

```
fun main(){
    var l = mutableListOf<LocalTime>()
    (0..24).forEach {
        l.add(LocalTime.of(it,0))
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ananiya thanks for your reply. l.add(LocalTime.of(it, 0)); **LocalTime.of** is giving error **Call requires API level 26 (current min is 16): java.time.LocalTime#of**

Comment: You could wrap it inside `if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION.O)`

Comment: As long as you're on Android Gradle plugin 4.0 or newer, with [coreLibraryDesugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) you can use java.time.